# HTML form $_POST not being retrieve and set into PDO QUERY

Tags: php, html, pdo

I decided to leave in all the code to make it less confusing to those who see this.

On line #57, the only form on this page, I'm trying to $_POST the id that equals the post_iD. 
Everything uploads correctly to MySQL besides the post_iD.

I always get a Notice: Undefined index: post_iD on $post_iD = $_POST['post_iD']; inside the if(isset($POST['comment'])).

I'm sure the issue is with how I'm trying to retrieve the post_iD inside the form, and not any issues with the PDO but html as PDO the data is being inserted correctly besides the post_iD which I have mentioned.

I'm using post_iD to loop posts from database, it works besides inside the form, any enlightenment with this issue?

Code Below.

```
if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
    $comment    = $_POST['comment'];
    $post_iD    = $_POST['post_iD'];
    $data       = $Wall->Insert_Comment( $uiD, $post_iD, $comment, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );
}

if ( $updatesarray ){
    foreach ($updatesarray as $data){
        $post_iD    = $data['post_iD'];
        $orimessage = $data['message']; 
        $message    = tolink(htmlcode($data['message']));
        $time       = $data['created'];
        $mtime      = date("g:i", $time);
        $username   = $data['username'];
        $uploads    = $data['uploads'];
        $uiD        = $data['uid_fk'];
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item" id="stbody<?php echo $post_iD;?>">
        <div class="loop-post">
            <div class="loop-post-content">
                <div class="loop-post-image">
                    <a href="" class="post-link">
                        <?php 
                            if ($uploads){ 
                                $s = explode(",", $uploads);
                                    foreach ($s as $a){
                                        $newdata = $Wall->Get_Upload_Image_Id($a);
                                        if ($newdata) echo "<a href='uploads/" . $newdata['image_path'] . "' rel='facebox'>
                                            <img src='uploads/" . $newdata['image_path'] . "' width='520' height='245' class='imgpreview attachment-top_story_post wp-post-image' /></a>";
                                    }   
                                echo "</div>";
                            }   
                        ?>
                    </a>
            </div>
            <div class="loop-post-byline">By <a rel="author" title="Posts by Emil Protalinski" href=""><?php echo $username;?></a> 
                <span class="date"><a href='<?php echo $base_url ?>status/<?php echo $post_iD; ?>'title='<?php echo $time;?>' class="timeposted"> — <?php echo $mtime;?></a></span>
            </div>
            <a class="post-link">                           
                <?php echo clear($message);?>
            </a>

            <div class="post_comment">
                <?php $x=1; include_once 'load_comments.php'; ?>

                <div class="commentupdate" id="commentbox<?php echo $post_iD;?>">
                    <div class="stcommentimg">
                        <img src="<?php echo $photo;?>" class="small_face">
                    </div>

                    <div class="stcommenttext">
                        <form method="POST" action="">
                            <textarea name="comment" class="comment" id="<?php echo $post_iD;?>" value="<?php echo $post_iD;?>"></textarea> #57
                            <input type="submit" value="comment">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } } else echo '<h3 id="noupdates">No Updates!</h3>';?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this...

```
<textarea name="comment" class="comment" id="comment-<?php echo $post_iD;?>"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="post_iD" name="post_iD" value="<?php echo $post_iD;?>" />
```

Cuz youre never passing the post_iD anywhere....this will pass it in hidden form...

And the value for your textarea wont be $post_iD, it will likely be a comment/post of some type....I assume you just had that for debugging

Comment: So simple, I was going to try that but I forgot. Thank you for your quick and perfect response, that will clear a lot of time ahead for me. I appreciate your time and response!

Answer (score 2):

You are never actually setting the `post_iD` variable anywhere. If you want to use it in the `$_POST` array you need to set it in the form first.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_iD" value="<?php echo $post_iD; ?>" />
  <textarea name="comment" class="comment" id="<?php echo $post_iD;?>" value="<?php echo $post_iD;?>"></textarea> #57
  <input type="submit" value="comment">
</form>
```